# Constructors, Ignore Arguments

Tags: c#, parameters, constructors

Is it possible to have a constructor in a class, that you can ignore certain arguments/parameters?

For example, I have this constructor

Car(color, make, model, wheels, type, doors)

Could I call this constructor and not include the type parameter?

Comment: You can use optional parameters and overloads as with every other function. But only the last parameters can be optional, so only making `type` optional doesn't work. If both `type` and `doors` are optional, you could use named parameters to only specify `doors` but not `type`.

Comment: As an alternative you could consider some kind of builder of factory.

Comment: Optional parameters, as @CodesInChaos said,maybe ordering your parameters to have optional ones at the end. Otherwise you can add another constructor (overloading): Car(color, make, model, wheels, doors). In this case 'type' will have a default value (or a calculated one).

Comment: Thank you, I believe this has helped me make some design decisions.

Answer (score 3):

[Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is exact solution to this problem. Especially if the combination of optional and required parameters get big, which would require tons of different constructors.

Comment: Thank you that link directly explains and will help me in the application I am building.  The car was just an example and not the actual application I am building, but I will be able to transpose it for my problem set.